# Am I Required to Pay to Receive a Certification I Earned on Company Time?

Tags: united-states, texas

I worked for a company that payed for my first aid and CPR training. I have since then quit the job and am working elsewhere, however I need to show I was re-certified. The prior company is now refusing to give me the certificate and is asking for me to pay $50 to receive it. All of this happened in Texas, United States of America.

Is this legal and allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you if it is legal. But they did it, so your choices are:

1. Contact whoever performed the training and ask whether they can give you a copy of those certificates. They may not be able to, they may charge a fee. The fee is likely less than $50.
2. Pay $50 to your previous employer.
3. Ask a lawyer to write a letter to the previous employer. It may work, but will cost you a lot more than $50.
4. Ask a lawyer to take them to court. It may work, but will cost you *considerably more* than $50.
5. Take the course again. I don't know about the cost in the USA, but you have a brand new certification, and you have brand new knowledge, so that is overall good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the website of the organization that taught the class. If you're lucky, the electronic certificate is sitting there waiting for you.